# Using tryCatch and source

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

Suppose I have two R files: `correct.R` and `broken.R`. What would be the best way of using `tryCatch` to check for errors?

Currently, I have

```
> x = tryCatch(source("broken.R"), error=function(e) e)
> x
 <simpleError in source("broken.R"): test.R:2:0: unexpected end of input
  1: x = {
     ^>
> y = tryCatch(source("correct.R"), error=function(e) e)
> y
 $value
 [1] 5

 $visible
 [1] FALSE
```

However, the way I've constructed the `tryCatch` means that I have to interrogate the `x` and `y` objects to determine if there has been an error.

Is there a better way of doing this?

---

The question comes from teaching. 100 students upload their R scripts and I run the scripts. To be nice, I'm planning on creating a simple function that determines if their function sources correctly. It only needs to return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Note that `tryCatch` will report only the first error it bumps onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm underthinking this, but since you're just looking for the boolean, you can just test for the existence of the `$visible`:

```
y <- tryCatch(source("broken.R"), error=function(e) e)
works <- !is.null(y$visible) #y$visible would be null if there were an error
```

Does that solve what you're looking for? You could wrap it in a loop (or use  `lapply`) like:

```
for(i in 1:length(students)) {
  works[i] <- !is.null(tryCatch(source(student_submissions[i]), error=function(e) e)$visible)
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, it just seemed clunky. I suppose I was looking for an `is.error` command.

Comment: er, with objects from try that is, not tryCatch

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon mdsumner's point, this is a simple implementation.

```
sources_correctly <- function(file)
{
  fn <- try(source(file))
  !inherits((fn, "try-error"))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
> tryCatch(stop("foo"), error = function(e) {
+ cat(e$message, "\n")
+ FALSE
+ })
foo 
[1] FALSE
```

Alternatively, you should consider Hadley's `testthat` package:

```
> expect_that(stop("foo"), is_a("numeric"))
Error in is.vector(X) : foo
```